# I have two arrays (1 Array of numbers + 1 Array of strings). How can I sort them the exact same way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, algorithm, sorting

I have two arrays (1 Array of numbers + 1 Array of strings). Here they are:

**Array #1:**

`let arrayOne = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 7, 7];`

**Array #2:**

`let arrayTwo = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];`

**My Question:**

I want to order the array of numbers in descending order (Largest to Smallest). How can I sort arrayOne (Array of Numbers) while sorting the array of strings the exact same way?

**My Code So Far:**

```
// Sorted Array
const sortedArray: Array<number> = sortArray(props.data[0], 'Descending');

// Graph Rank Items
const graphRankItems: Array<GraphRankItem> = [
  {
    label: convertMonthAbbreviationToFull(props.labels[props.data[0].indexOf(sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 1])] as MonthAbbreviation),
    value: sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 1].toLocaleString(),
  },
  {
    label: convertMonthAbbreviationToFull(props.labels[props.data[0].indexOf(sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 2])] as MonthAbbreviation),
    value: sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 2].toLocaleString(),
  },
  {
    label: convertMonthAbbreviationToFull(props.labels[props.data[0].indexOf(sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 3])] as MonthAbbreviation),
    value: sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 3].toLocaleString(),
  },
  {
    label: convertMonthAbbreviationToFull(props.labels[props.data[0].indexOf(sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 4])] as MonthAbbreviation),
    value: sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 4].toLocaleString(),
  },
  {
    label: convertMonthAbbreviationToFull(props.labels[props.data[0].indexOf(sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 5])] as MonthAbbreviation),
    value: sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 5].toLocaleString(),
  }
];
```

**My Issue:**

My current system is to sort the array and the find the index of that number in the original array, then extract the string from `arrayTwo`. However, that leads to issue when the same numbers are present and looks up the same index twice. It leaves out the second, third, and etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that

1. [maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the first array to an array of objects that contain both value and index, then
2. [sorts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) that array based on value, and finally
3. maps the resulting indexes to values of the second array.

```js
const a1 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 7, 7];
const a2 = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June',
            'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

const result = a1.map((v, i) => ({v, i}))
                 .sort((a, b) => b.v - a.v)
                 .map(({i}) => a2[i]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming November and December is the largest side.

If so:

```
let arrayTwo = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

// Sorts array in descending order
// If you want to ascending just interchange a and b.
arrayTwo.sort((a,b) => {
    return arrayTwo.indexOf(b) - arrayTwo.indexOf(a)
})
```

Array .sort [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).